# Invalid argument supplied foreach php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach

I'm trying to display products from cart but I receive following errors (see below). I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong... A detailed answer with explanations would be nice. I tried to find solutions to my problem without success. ***I do understand*** what an undefined variable means but I don't know how to fix it in this particular case.

> Notice: Undefined variable: row
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
<?php
    require_once 'core/config.php';
    $cartQ  = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);
    foreach ($row as $product) {
        $productQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN cart ON product.id=cart.product_id ");
        $product      = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQuery);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ)) {
        }
?>
        <tr class="p">
            <td class="image"><img src="<?= $product['image_1']; ?>" /></td>
            <td class="name"><?= $product['prod_name']; ?></td>
            <td class="price"><?= money($product['price']); ?></td>
        </tr>

<?php
    }
?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, look at the error, look at your code, where is $row defined?

Comment: look at this line `foreach($row as $product){` the variable `$row`. in the lines above you are setting a var nammed `$result` maybe that it was you were intending to reference. or maybe you left out a block of code between those that references it

Comment: @Devon: dude I have been sleep walking for days okay. Relax.

Comment: I'm plenty relaxed, thank you for the concern though.  Just pointing out that reading the error is useful.

Comment: @happymacarts: Thanks for your answer. See that's the thing, when I use `$product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ);` the product `image_1`, `prod_name` and `price` display fine however two things go wrong: 1) the number of rows is wrong (way too many rows) and 2) it displays the same product over and over. It should display only two rpoducts right now; a t-shirt and a hat but instead I see 7 t-shirts and no hat.

Comment: your loop is not looping over the item you are trying to. check your query seperate from your php logic to make sure it is returning what you intend

Comment: Didn't you post this same question yesterday? I remember the variable `$cartQ`.

Comment: You're only fetching 1 row from `cart`. You need a loop to keep calling `mysqli_fetch_assoc($cartQ)` to get all the items in the cart.

Comment: Why do you even need the first query and the outer loop? The second query that joins `product` and `cart` gets everything you need.

Comment: @Barmar: It does not... I have tried so many variables of this code without success trust me!

Comment: @Barmar: the first query serves another purpose in the code.

Comment: It doesn't serve any purpose in the code you've shown. Nothing from that query is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the first query and the `foreach` loop, they're not needed. The `JOIN` query returns all the information you need to display.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
<?php
    require_once 'core/config.php';
    $productQuery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN cart ON product.id=cart.product_id ");
    while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQuery)) {
        ?>
        <tr class="p">
            <td class="image"><img src="<?= $product['image_1']; ?>" /></td>
            <td class="name"><?= $product['prod_name']; ?></td>
            <td class="price"><?= money($product['price']); ?></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
    }
?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```